# How do I conditionally change the value of a field depending on the value chosen in another?

Tags: 8, webforms

This was so easy in webform 4.x. However, I cannot seem to find it in webform 5.x.

I am creating a form using webform 5.1, and I need to set the value of the fees for a particular grade for an instrument, using conditional values (see attached screenshot for webform 4.x). So a person chooses the instrument, the grade in which he/she is to appear for examination, and then chooses whether it's a performance (practical) or grade (theory) exam. The fees value for the exam is programmatically chosen from a list of choices in the 'fees' field, using conditionals.

[image: screenshot of the conditionals in webform 4.x]

Now, for the life of me, I cannot figure out a way to do the same thing using the latest version of the module on drupal 8. Have the developers of webform changed things so that it is now impossible to do it in version 5 or is there a way that I am not aware of?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Conditionally setting an element's value is not currently supported in Webform 8.x-5.x.

Comment: Thanks. Are there plans to have that functionality back in the near future, or via an add-on module?

Comment: Webform for Drupal 8 is now using Drupal's #states API which does not support this functionality and I don't see any easy way to add it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That functionality however, was important. Will it be possible to implement it (or something similar) using a contrib module?

Comment: Have you tried some Javascript? It appears quite straightforward to add some JS to a Webform in D8 (easier than in D7).

Comment: I also need this functionality. Is it supported in the meantime?

Comment: Nope. I guess you have to be a full-blown programmer to use Drupal. Otherwise, use WordPress or something.

Comment: I agree it is a real pain to lose this functionality.  Karin's comment seems the most straightforward way - if anyone has seen a tutorial on this anywhere, it would be good to point it out or provide an example. I can see the CSS/JS section in Settings, I assume this is the correct place?